# Unable to monitor each slave's test results from the master pc

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, stress-testing

I tried distributed testing with 3 pcs including my Pc, and it is the master. I created remote object form my one also. So I could send requests from my Pc also.

I Send 1000 requests under 3 ramp up period with no loops. When running the test plan, I only can see 1000 response results with the listeners, not 3000. I was unable to see other slave machines responses. How could I see every results, or is there any specific listener to view those?

The listeners I used are; View results in table, view results table, Aggregate graph, summary report and perfmon metrics collector.

How Could view all results including slave machines?

Comment: using master machine as a slave as well? this is unusual. Have you tried with 1 master and 2 slaves. Do you get results in that case?

Comment: I tried it, in that case, master machine doesn't view any result, but when I look at slaves console, it show a log like this; "Starting the test on host 192.168.24.136 @ Tue Mar 29 14:56:03 IST 2016 (1459243563557)

Comment: You should first keep trying with 2 slaves setup. For starter, you can verify that if your remote machines really generate load when you start test? Are the ports opened as mentioned in guide?

Comment: yes. I tried with 2 slaves, by adding requests separately. One slave didn't respond, as it's properties file had not included master machine's IP, Then I tried with both slaves at the same time, worked. and also created remote object in master machine and ran the test plan. It also worked properly.

Comment: Great, so your problem is solved now and it was related to configuration :)